# Pattern Matching Design

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I recently wrote some code like the block below and it left me with thoughts that the design could be improved if I was more knowledgeable on functional programming abstractions.

```
sealed trait Foo
case object A extends Foo
case object B extends Foo
case object C extends Foo
.
.
.

object Foo {
  private def someFunctionSemanticallyRelatedToA() = { // do stuff }
  private def someFunctionSemanticallyRelatedToB() = { // do stuff }
  private def someFunctionSemanticallyRelatedToC() = { // do stuff }
  .   
  .   
  .   

  def somePublicFunction(x : Foo)  = x match {
    case A => someFunctionSemanticallyRelatedToA()
    case B => someFunctionSemanticallyRelatedToB()
    case C => someFunctionSemanticallyRelatedToC()
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is the somePublicFunction() suffering from code smell or even the whole design? My concern is that the list of value constructors could grow quite big.
2. Is there a better FP abstraction to handle this type of design more elegantly or even concisely?

Answer (score 5):

You've just run into the [expression problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem). In your code sample, the problem is that potentially every time you add or remove a case from your `Foo` algebraic data type, you'll need to modify every single match (like in `somePublicFunction`) against values of `Foo`. In Nimrand's answer, the problem is in the opposite end of the spectrum: you can add or remove cases from `Foo` easily, but every time you want to add or remove a *behaviour* (a method), you'll need to modify every subclass of `Foo`.

There are various proposals to solve the expression problem, but one interesting functional way is Oleg Kiselyov's [Typed Tagless Final Interpreters](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/), which replaces each case of the algebraic data type with a *function* that returns some abstract value that's considered to be equivalent to that case. Using generics (i.e. type parameters), these functions can all have compatible types and work with each other no matter when they were implemented. E.g., I've implemented an example of building and evaluating an arithmetic expression tree using TTFI: https://github.com/yawaramin/scala-ttfi

Comment: Interesting information.  Agreed that my solution has the opposite problem.  However, if the set of abstract methods is relatively small and unlikely to change often, it's a good solution, given the tools we have right now, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is a bit too abstract to give you a confident answer.  However, if the list of subclasses of Foo is likely to grow/change in the future, I would be inclined to make it an abstract method of Foo, and then implement the logic for each case in the sub classes.  Then you just call Foo.myAbstractMethod() and polymorphism handles everything neatly.

This keeps the code specific to each object with the object itself, which is keeps things more neatly organized.  It also means that you can add new subclasses of Foo without having to jump around to multiple places in code to augment the existing match statements elsewhere in the code.

Case classes and pattern-matching work best when the set of sub-classes is relatively small and fixed.  For example, Option[T] there are only two sub-classes, Some[T] and None.  That will NEVER change, because to change that would be to fundamentally change what Option[T] represents.  Therefore, it's a good candidate for pattern-matching.